# Issue with mouse coordinates in the latest flash player and latest browsers

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, firefox, flex4

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" creationComplete="creationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            private var objImageDetails:Object = new Object();
            private function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                var contextMenu:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
                contextMenu.hideBuiltInItems();
                var menuItem:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem("Paste\u00A0");
                menuItem.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT,onSelectPaste);
                //menuItem.enabled = false;
                contextMenu.customItems.push(menuItem);
                this.contextMenu = contextMenu

                objImageDetails.source = "assets/flower.jpeg";
            }

            private function onSelectPaste(event:ContextMenuEvent):void
            {
                var objImage:Image = new Image();
                objImage.source = objImageDetails.source;
                objImage.x = this.mouseX;
                objImage.y = this.mouseY;
                this.addElement(objImage);
            }   

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <mx:Image id="FlowerImage" source="assets/flower.jpeg" />
</s:Application>
```

After executing the application please right click on the application and select paste. Keep on doing that. At some time u can face the issue. The image gets pasted in some other x/y rather than pasting at mouseX/mouseY.

I face problem in getting the mouse coordinates from the latest browsers using right click. Previously it was working fine with older browsers like Firefox 5.5.
the mouseY value moves some pixels down on right click so it affects the paste opration
It does not paste at exact location. It happens some times.

Comment: "No such browser exception: Firefox 5.5". Please don't use such vague terms: what browser version does this work in and what version doesn't? It is easy enough to download an older Firefox version to test. Also, have you considered the possibility that the browser has nothing to do with it and the problem is caused by a Flash update?

Comment: +1 vote "I tried the same with older browser it works fine and not in newer version browser such as 7.0.1 to 5.5"

Comment: Sounds more like a code issue. objTemplateCanvas is probably wrapped in another container. POST CODE it really isn't that hard to not be vague. Also post embed code. I would bet you are using wmode=transparent.

Comment: Since there is no native right-click event for browser-based SWFs, are you using `ContextMenuEvent.MENU_SELECT`?  Or JavaScript hack like [this](http://code.google.com/p/custom-context-menu/)?

Comment: Hi Rohler   Ya i am using ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT

Comment: @saradaprasad, If you're using that event, why do you even need x/y coordinates to figure out which item you're selecting?

Comment: @J_A_X i think u didn't get my point. am using the contextmenu for copy and pasting in empty area, so here i need the copy of object in the particular x/y where the user right clicks and selects paste.

Comment: Kinda of hard to help without more code, but I'd imagine it's because you're trying to get the mouse coordinates *after* the user clicked on the menu item, and not where the original right click is, which should be stored.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a listener on `MOUSE_MOVE` to store the last mouse coordinates and use these in `onSelectPaste`.

Comment: I think this might not be perfect solution.